Apache httpd forward proxy - remove Proxy-agent header from CONNECT requests
Is there any way to remove Proxy-agent  header (set to Apache/2.4.6.2(OS)) from CONNECT requests going through Apache httpd configured as forward proxy (forwarding requests to another uplink proxy)?
"RequestHeader unset Proxy-agent" in config - won't work, Proxy-agent: Apache/2.4.6.2(OS) is still in place at outgoing requests.

You can start with "ServerSignature Off" and "ServerTokens Prod"
